# Changed RMAN backup location, but still seeing the FULL DB backup going to the old location?

Tags: oracle, backup, restore, rman

I just recently changed the     `db_recovery_file_dest` value to our new directory location. I can see the archive logs going to the new location and the backupsets.

However, our FULL DB backup is still showing that it's writing to the old location. Any thoughts?

Fyi, I'm not very Oracle savvy, I'm just picking up new information everyday since our Senior DBA just passed away.

Edit:

Here is the configuration. It seems to mostly be default settings.

```
RMAN> show all;
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name WEBPRD01 are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 7 DAYS;
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION ON;
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK BACKUP TYPE TO COMPRESSED BACKUPSET PARALLELISM 1;
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BASIC' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE ; # default
CONFIGURE RMAN OUTPUT TO KEEP FOR 7 DAYS; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE; # default
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO '/u01/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbs/snapcf_WEBPRD01.f'; # default
```

Comment: Can you locate and share your full backup script? Also connect via RMAN and share the results of `show all;`

Comment: db_recovery_file_dest only specifies the directory to be used as the base of the FRA.  It does not, in itself, control the writing of archive logs, backups, or anything else.  The backup command itself has to specify to use the FRA .... or not ... with the FORMAT clause.  And you need to be aware that if a backup specifically names a directory within the FRA base, then it is not really using the features of the FRA, it is only consuming disk space without the FRA bookkeeping knowing about it.  As Andrew said, we need to see the actual backup script.

Comment: I have edited and pasted the RMAN configuration.

Comment: The configuration is not the script that performs the backup, it is just the default settings. We need to see the actual RMAN commands used to generate the backup itself.